# SpriteKit - Stop Clicks on Sprite From Acting Upon Children

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I currently use the following to create a button with text using SpriteKit:

```
SKLabelNode *startButtonText = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Verdana-Bold"];
startButtonText.text = @"Start";
startButtonText.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
startButtonText.fontSize = 24;
startButtonText.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2-10);
startButtonText.name=@"startButton";

SKShapeNode *startButton = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
startButton.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(center.x-65.0 , center.y-20.0, 130.0, 40.0)].CGPath;
startButton.fillColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.188 green:0.196 blue:0.161 alpha:1];
startButton.strokeColor = nill;
startButtonText.name=@"startButton";

[startButton addChild:startButtonText];
[self addChild:startButton];
```

My goal is to make it so that when the screen is touched, the touch only registers startButton not start startButtonText via:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    NSLog(@"%@",node.name);
}
```

In action script, you would simply use:

```
mouseChildren = false;
```

Is there anyway this is possible?

Comment: You have set the name property for both `startButtonText` and `startButton` as `@"startButton"`. This is probably why the same name is being logged in the touch delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give both buttons a different name. It looks like there's a copy & paste error in your code.
Then check in your touchesBegan which button has been pressed and react on both the same way:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"startButton"]||[node.name isEqualToString:@"startButtonText"]) {
...
}
```